# How to count objects related to an item displayed in ListView?

Tags: python, django, listview, django-views, django-generic-views

I'm trying to use a **ListView** to display all my towns.

However, i'd like to display, for each town, the number of citizens living in it.

## Models.py

```
class Town(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Citizen(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    town = models.ForeignKey(Town)
```

## Views.py

```
class TownView(ListView):
    model = Town
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TownView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['towns'] = Town.objects.all().prefetch_related('players')
        return context
```

This does not work, because the prefetch_related would only work if I there was a player attribute in the town view, perhaps through a manytomany field.

How can I retrieve, for each town, the number of citizens who have their foreigkey set to that town ?

Also, what would my template look like ? Currently, it looks like this :

## Template

```
<table>
{% for town in open_towns %}
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/town/join/{{ town.slug }}/">{{ town.name }}</a></td>
        <td>population : {{ Player.objects.filter(town=town).count() }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

But this is obviously wrong too.

Answer (score 5):

What you actually need here is annotation. You can do it without overriding any methods at all.

```
from django.db.models import Count

class TownView(ListView):
    queryset = Town.objects.all().annotate(citizen_count=Count('citizen'))
```

Now each element in the object_list has a `citizen_count` property.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) functionality what you need:

```
Town.objects.annotate(population=Count('players'))
```

And in the template:

```
<table>
{% for town in open_towns %}
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/town/join/{{ town.slug }}/">{{ town.name }}</a></td>
        <td>population : {{ town.population }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```